# Google Analytics UTM URLs in code

Tags: url, google-analytics

I would like to create a campaign to track an advert sent by email. I have read about using Google Analytics and UTM URLs however I am slightly confused on how to use them. Must I generate a tagged link and use it in my email campaign in order for the campaign to work?

Also, if I want to track a banner on my website must I change the URLs in the code of the website itself?

Thanks

Comment: This question isn't programing related please try the Google analytic community on Google+ https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537

Comment: Yes apologies for that but I didn't know where to ask it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the utm information in the ads urls will cause that information to become associated with session data automatically.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=promo_email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=january_promo
```

will automatically have the ga:source set to "promo_email" ga::medium set to "email" and ga:campaign set to "january_promo".

Alternatively you can simplify your strategy but only tagging a utm_id

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_id=1234
```

and then use the [Data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4522476?ref_topic=6015090) feature to upload custom campaign dimensions associated with that utm_id, or ga:campaignCode.